# How can I access a global C array of structs from a Rust library?

Tags: c, rust, ffi

I am porting a static library to Rust that will be linked with a C application which will provide a global array. Here is the definition of the struct and array:

```c
typedef struct glkunix_argumentlist_struct {
    char *name;
    int argtype;
    char *desc;
} glkunix_argumentlist_t;
extern glkunix_argumentlist_t glkunix_arguments[];
```

There is no length parameter, instead the last entry in the array will be `{NULL, 0, NULL}` ([example](https://github.com/erkyrath/glulxe/blob/master/unixstrt.c#L28)), which you test for when looping through the array.

I think this is the correct Rust representation for the struct:

```rust
#[repr(C)]
struct GlkUnixArgument {
    name: *const c_char,
    argtype: c_int,
    desc: *const c_char,
}
```

The Rust Nomicon [shows how to define an extern for a single integer](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/ffi.html#accessing-foreign-globals).

I've seen that if you have a length parameter [you can use `std::slice::from_raw_parts` to get a slice](https://s3.amazonaws.com/temp.michaelfbryan.com/arrays/index.html#receiving-an-array-from-c), but we don't have a length yet. I could modify the C code to provide one, but I would like to be able to provide a drop-in replacement if I can.

I haven't yet seen how to just create one single Rust struct from a extern. Though I did just have the idea of just `std::slice::from_raw_parts` with a length of 1.

Is there a better way to more directly define an extern struct in Rust?

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ddeab9d1af2a62ecf6ce095dd667590d

Comment: @PitaJ But do I need to use anything like `from_raw_parts` (obviously it would be a different function) before accessing the struct fields?

Comment: "There is no length parameter" a C array have ALWAYS a length, if not it's not an array by definition. You can have it by doing `const size_t len = sizeof glkunix_arguments / sizeof *glkunix_arguments;`

Comment: @Stargateur I meant no length parameter was provided to the functions. I could change the end user code but then it wouldn't be a drop in replacement.

Comment: Again, no length no array, you can't pass an array as parameter to a C function, you can only pass a pointer to a whatever you want but not an array. Semantic is very important in a language like C, if you say array it's an array so it HAD an length.

Comment: @Stargateur I never said it didn't have a length. I said there's no length **parameter**, by which I meant it is not exposed as a global that I can simply access with an extern from Rust, nor is it ever given to the library's functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must calculate the length of your C array before creating the slice with `from_raw_parts`:

```rust
use libc::{c_char, c_int};

#[repr(C)]
pub struct GlkUnixArgument {
    name: *const c_char,
    argtype: c_int,
    desc: *const c_char,
}

pub unsafe fn glkunix_arguments() -> &'static [GlkUnixArgument] {
    extern "C" {
        pub static glkunix_arguments: *const GlkUnixArgument;
    }

    let len = (0..)
        .take_while(|i| {
            let arg = glkunix_arguments.offset(*i);
            (*arg).name != std::ptr::null()
                || (*arg).argtype != 0
                || (*arg).desc != std::ptr::null()
        })
        .count();

    std::slice::from_raw_parts(glkunix_arguments, len)
}
```

You can even map the C struct to a Rust struct:

```rust
use libc::{c_char, c_int, strlen};
use std::{ptr, slice, str};

pub struct GlkUnixArgument {
    pub name: &'static str,
    pub argtype: i32,
    pub desc: &'static str,
}

pub unsafe fn glkunix_arguments() -> Vec<GlkUnixArgument> {
    extern "C" {
        pub static glkunix_arguments: *const GlkUnixArgument_;
    }

    #[repr(C)]
    pub struct GlkUnixArgument_ {
        name: *const c_char,
        argtype: c_int,
        desc: *const c_char,
    }

    impl GlkUnixArgument_ {
        fn is_not_empty(&self) -> bool {
            self.name != ptr::null() || self.argtype != 0 || self.desc != ptr::null()
        }
    }

    unsafe fn c_str_to_rust_str(s: *const i8) -> &'static str {
        str::from_utf8(slice::from_raw_parts(s as *const u8, strlen(s))).unwrap()
    }

    let len = (0..)
        .map(|i| glkunix_arguments.offset(i))
        .take_while(|&arg| (*arg).is_not_empty())
        .count();

    slice::from_raw_parts(glkunix_arguments, len)
        .iter()
        .map(|args| GlkUnixArgument {
            name: c_str_to_rust_str(args.name),
            desc: c_str_to_rust_str(args.desc),
            argtype: args.argtype,
        })
        .collect()
}
```

Using a lazy construct can ensure that you're doing the operation only once.

Comment: Oh interesting, I've never seen externs or structs inside functions before. Thanks!

Comment: Rust is super flexible in this aspect. You can put whatever you want in a function.

Comment: Actually, you can put whatever you want in a scope, I can mix and match `fn`, `mod`, `struct`, `enum`, `union`, `type` aliases, `trait`s, `const`s, `extern`, `static`[`mut`], etc; with some restrictions (IE, you cannot put anything other than members inside a `struct`/`enum`/`union` declaration)

Comment: Four years later and I'm finally trying this, and I can't get it to work. I think the problem is https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/54450 - `glkunix_arguments[]` is an array, but `*const GlkUnixArgument_` expects a pointer, and so it doesn't get the correct address.

Comment: I followed the advice of that issue, and added a helper function in C to return a pointer to the array. That seems to be working.